# Application going to different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

i am doing one application.In that if i press one button for service and go to some other application and come to my application,it's showing some other view controller instead of correct view controller and app will struck and crash.So how to solve this.

Comment: Post the code. How can anyone know without seeing code?????????

Comment: @FawadMasud you need more question marks at the end of your comment